# Migrating New Platform License Types from Prod to Sandbox

Tags: licenses, migration

Can we migrate newly provisioned platform licenses from production to dev environments without needing to do a refresh?

Comment: I'm looking forward to a response, but I believe the only option outside of a refresh is a SFDC exception.  Perhaps an extract of the metadata, a refresh, and a full overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the refreshing you could log a ticket and ask the support to add the license to the sandbox. Since you are already paying for it on production, my guess is your chances are good to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

You can (sometimes) get the licenses matched through the automated feature, or (usually) by contacting support. They can adjust licenses without the need for a refresh. See the related information on [How do I match or bring over new licenses between my Production and Sandbox orgs without a refresh?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193571&language=en_US), and [Match Production Licenses feature missing on Sandbox](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5DkAAK). You can only enable the pilot feature if your sandbox and production versions are in sync (e.g. 33.0). Apparently, at some point in the near future, it will eventually go GA, in which case, you'll no longer need to log cases to sync licenses.